# Use jQuery zoom on background image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'd like to use the [jQuery zoom](https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom) on background images. The problem is, it works on images with img tags only. Is there any way to use it on background-images aswell?
I can't use img tag, because this value comes from javascript.
For example, I have this div:

```
<div class="main-image" style="background-image: url("image.jpg");"></div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.main-image').zoom();
        });
```

```
 (function() {
                let gallerys = document.querySelectorAll('.gallery');
                gallerys.forEach(gallery => {
                    updateGalleryPictures(gallery);
                });
            })();

            function updateGalleryPictures(gallery) {
                // Get gallery's thumbnail images
                let thumbnails = gallery.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail');
                // Change the background-image property on click
                thumbnails.forEach(thumbnail => {
                    thumbnail.addEventListener('click', () => {
                        updateMainImage(gallery, thumbnail.src)
                    });
                });
                // Initialize background-image property using the 1st thumbnail image
                let firstThumbnail = thumbnails[0];
                if (firstThumbnail === null || firstThumbnail === undefined) return;
                updateMainImage(gallery, firstThumbnail.src)
            }

            function updateMainImage(gallery, src) {
                // Get main image and check if it exists
                let mainImage = gallery.querySelector('.main-image');
                if (mainImage === null) return;
                mainImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src + ')';
            }
```

Comment: I think you forget the quotes in CSS inside the URL. Like: background-image: url("image.jpg");

Comment: Yes, thank you, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's literally [the first example you see on the documentation page](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)... What problems are you facing with implementing this?

Comment: I edited the question with the javascript code that changes the background url. I don't understand how and where should I implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the source code of the plugin in question. https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/blob/master/jquery.zoom.js - it is not designed to work on background images as you can see from lines https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/blob/master/jquery.zoom.js#L117 and https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/blob/master/jquery.zoom.js#L231 two properties which aren't available on divs.

You may get some mileage using pure CSS moving on mousemove something like:

```js
    $('.main-image').mousemove(function(e){
        var amountMovedX = (e.pageX * -1 / 2);
        var amountMovedY = (e.pageY * -1 / 2);
        $(this).css({
               'background-size': '200%',
               'background-position': amountMovedX + 'px ' + amountMovedY + 'px'} 
        );
    });
```

```css
.main-image {
background-image:url('https://www.travelandleisure.com/sites/default/files/styles/tnl_redesign_article_landing_page/public/1453920892/DUBAI-554088081-ABOVE0116.jpg?itok=dcoZnCrc');
background-size: 100%;
display:block;
height:200px;
width:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I decided not to use zoom, but accepted your answer because it solved the problem.